# Android Canvas Using Too Much CPU

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm making **simple** 2D game with canvas in android. I think it's enough for my game.
But locking and unlocking canvas operations using around %40-%50 CPU.
**Is this normal?** or **What should i do**?
**There is my game loop code:**

```
while(GVars.isGameRunning){
        c=holder.lockCanvas();
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255, 229, 43, 68));
        c.drawRect(GMethods.createRec(0,0,GVars.size[0], 90),p);
        for (int i = 0; i < GVars.size[0]/110; i++){
            c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(i*100+30,100,i*100+130,100+100),10,10,p);
        }
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
        p.setTextSize(50);
        c.drawText("Simple text:", 0,60, p);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        try{Thread.sleep(GVars.waitTime/*waitTime =30*/);}catch(Exception ex){};
    }
```

Sorry for my English.

**Edit:**
I tried once again like this.(In main thread) And it's now using %10 of cpu. I think it's what i want. :D **Thanks!**

```
   @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c){
    p.setTextSize(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < GVars.size[0]/110; i++){
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255,183, 33, 53));
        c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(i*100+i*10, 100+5, i*100+100+i*10, 100+100+10),10,10,p);
    }
    p.setColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
    c.drawText("Test:", 0,60, p);
    invalidate();
    try{Thread.sleep(20);}catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

Comment: You should use the Android event mechanism rather than your own loop.

Comment: p.s. You should also include the class and method which contains your code in order to provide more context.

Comment: You should not have `Thread.sleep()` in `onDraw()`. This will still freeze the app's main thread. You do not need to call `invalidate()` either.

Comment: Since you are making a game, you probably want to do animations. You need to learn about the standard techniques to do this. In particular, `onDraw()` should draw one frame of the animation. You have to do some bookkeeping to make the animation smooth and consistent.

Comment: Sorry, but how can i draw one frame repeatedly with onDraw()? I think invalidate() doing this.

Comment: The Android event framework calls `onDraw()` when it is needed. You do not have to worry about this yourself. If you are doing animations in your game, you will call `invalidate()` whenever the game data changes, for example in an `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop in your code blocks the main event thread. Instead, you should use the event mechanism from the Android API. Specifically, you need to override [`View.onDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)).

Comment: No, it's not blocking. Loop is in another thread. Sorry, i didn't mention it.

Comment: And i tried override onDraw() but it was still using too much cpu.

Comment: @zekikos You need to show what you did. With the current code, show the class and method which contains it. Also show what you tried to do in `onDraw()`. You may have thought you were running the loop in another thread, but that is impossible since you can only use views in the main UI thread. If you try to use them in another thread, your app would crash with an exception.

Comment: I tried once again as you say. It's now using %5-%10 of cpu. Thanks!